# With how many women did Kirk have an affair?

Tags: star-trek

In the 1966 TV series, I find a new beautiful woman in almost every episode who had met Kirk before. They talk to Kirk in a very sweet way and they even kiss him. I want to know the exact number of those girls. Maybe Kirk mentioned this in conversation?

Comment: All of them? Almost as many as Riker got?

Comment: kirk had affairs with women, not girls

Comment: @dmckee Riker had more than twice as many seasons to work with...

Comment: @Ward True, but not every episode featured Riker, where as Kirk was likely in a prominent role of nearly every TOS episode.

Comment: @steve How do you know when girls become women in alien cultures?

Comment: @Xantec Good point, but I just can't accept Riker as a serious challenger for Kirk's "Space Slut" title.

Comment: This is unclear on several points: 1) Do you mean how many had he had affairs with before the series started, or during?  Or before and during?  and 2) Does it count the movies, or just the TV series?  (And if movies, does it count the reboot movie with Chris Pine as Kirk?)  Kirk never gave any specifics about his relationships.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just list those Kirk did NOT have an affair with?

Comment: @DVK Yes.. it'd be more easier. :)

Comment: @Kevin - They knew they were women when Kirk's charms worked on them

Comment: None.  Kirk wasn't married so they weren't affairs.  ;)

Comment: [Meta Discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/are-multiple-variations-of-a-question-with-subtle-distinctions-duplicate)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two.

- Priestess Miramanee [S03E03 The Paradise Syndrome]
- Deela [S03E11 Wink of an Eye]

All the other women he just flirted with and/or kissed, but those two women are the only times in which there was evidence that they actually had sex (which is what I'm considering an affair).

Source:
http://allyourtrekarebelongto.us/kirkgirls.htm

Comment: It depends on what the meaning of the word "is" is.

Comment: He spent the night with a woman "given" to him in _Bread and Circuses_.

Comment: What about [Carol Marcus](http://memory-alpha.org/en/wiki/Carol_Marcus) ?

Comment: @Pureferret That wasnt mentioned till STWoK

Comment: @OghmaOsiris oh? I didn't realise, but it does occur before  when the TV series is set.

Comment: Maybe so, But the question specifically asks about TOS the series. The relationship may have happened during the time frame, but it was never actually shown on screen during the series, so it can be assumed it was either before the series happened, or just after.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - very good work!

Answer (score 5):

None, Strictly speaking the relationships he had with Priestess Miramanee and Deela (courtesy of  [Oghma's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15343/3804)) occurred before his [two and half year marriage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture_%28novel%29) to Vice Admiral Lori Ciana and thus don't really count as affairs in the *strictest* sense.

Comment: I think perhaps you are confusing "affair" with "extramarital affair".

Comment: @Fruitbat, that's the only context I've heard Affair used in...Hmm, I see your point.